# Continious aggregates (keeping aggregated data in a fresh state) for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, aggregate, materialized-view

I build a PostgreSQL database for movie db platform. This DB is heavy loaded for readings of many related data.

Here is simplified schema what I have:

```
create table items
(
    id                  bigint generated always as identity
        primary key,
    -- item type is a simple ENUM value (movie, series)
    type                item_type                                               not null,

    -- and also title, description, age rating restrictions and etc.

    weighted_rating     double,
    created_at          timestamp with time zone default now()                  not null,
    updated_at          timestamp with time zone default now()                  not null,
);

create table item_genres
(
    item_id  bigint not null
        constraint item_genres_item_id_fk
            references items,
    genre_id bigint not null
        constraint item_genres_genre_id_fk
            references genres,
    primary key (item_id, genre_id)
);

create table item_countries
(
    item_id    bigint not null
        constraint item_counties_item_id_fk
            references items,
    country_id bigint not null
        constraint item_counties_country_id_fk
            references countries,
    primary key (item_id, country_id)
);

create table item_crew_members
(
    item_id        bigint                                 not null
        constraint item_crew_members_item_id_fk
            references items,
    person_id      bigint                                 not null
        constraint item_crew_members_person_id_fk
            references persons,
    role           item_crew_member_type                  not null,
    role_details   text,
    "order"        integer                                not null
        constraint item_crew_members_order_check
            check ("order" >= 0),
    primary key (item_id, person_id, role),
    constraint item_crew_member_unique_order_per_type_item_idx
        unique (item_id, role, "order")
            deferrable initially deferred
);

create table item_related_items
(
    item_id     bigint                                 not null
        constraint item_related_items_item_id_fk
            references items,
    rel_item_id bigint                                 not null
        constraint item_related_items_rel_item_id_fk
            references items,
    rel_type    related_item_rel_type                  not null,
    "order"     integer                                not null
        constraint item_related_items_order_check
            check ("order" >= 0),
    primary key (item_id, rel_item_id, rel_type),
    constraint item_related_items_unique_order_per_type_item_idx
        unique (item_id, rel_type, "order")
            deferrable initially deferred
);
```

Here is some sort of operations I'd like to optimize:

- Retrieving movie information, e.g. by ID with all its related data (genres, countries, crew, related movies, etc.)
- Searching movies: by genres, countries, title, years

And especially I'd like to have lower latency as possible (retrieve results in less then 1ms threshold).

My dataset size is: 1 million of movies, 21.5 million of crew members, 2 million of relations between movies and genres, 1 million of relations between movie and countries.

So, I started with two approaches:

- Materialized view
- Aggregation table

Both of these approaches are performing well in terms of performance, but have a cons in maintenance:

- Materialized view - have to compute all results from scratch, it could take a minutes to refresh data. And this is not what I want to do every time when one movie was updated in DB.
- Aggregation table - solves problem described above for Mat. view, but introduce new problems - I have to track somehow if there something was changed in movies table or in its related tables, and then update record in aggregation table. This will involve a lot of complex logic, triggers etc (and I guess If I choose triggers approach - bulk operations with movies, e.g. weighted rating recalculation will take too many time)

There's also pg_ivm extension that helps to implement incrementally updated materialized views in Postgres (but as I see on their github there's a lot of performance issues and bugs). And it seems to me that it works like an aggregation table, but solves problems with maintenance that exists with raw aggregation table.

On another side there is TimeScale DB (time-series db built as Postgres extension) which has Continuous Aggregates implementation, but unfortunately these CAGGs are designed to store time-series data grouped by time buckets.

And there's also Materialize DB (written in Rust) that looks promising, its especially designed to aggregate data in near real-time periods. It offers native integration with PostgreSQL to ingest data through logical replication protocol, and support almost all PostgreSQL features (and implements PostgreSQL wire protocol).

So, my question is: is there anything else for Postgres to keep aggregated data in a fresh state, without maintenance pain and reasonable delays?

Comment: "*retrieve results in less then 1ms threshold*" - Why 1ms?

Comment: @J.D. <1ms is good enough timing for required performance metrics. I'd like to handle as many concurrent queries as possible. Reading performance is most important part for final application, and I want to make sure that at least on the DB side everything works fast

Comment: Write triggers that keep an aggregate table updated whenever you modify the underlying tables.

Comment: @DmitryK. 1ms is pretty arbitrary though and not realistic if you really want to support queries like "*Searching movies: by genres, countries, title, years*" when your data is in the millions, unless you want to spend a lot of money. The average person can't tell the difference between 200ms or anything less btw.

Comment: @J.D.I agree, search by title would take much more time then 1ms. Actually in my tests with GIN trgm ops index on title it could take from 10ms up to 50ms, For filtering by genres/countries I did a little trick with de-normalized view of data, I've added two columns: genre_ids and country ids with datatype int[] and GIN index on both of them, and use @> operator to find matches. (ofc when multiple search conditions are specified "bitmap and" will be planned). BTW: I think that for search operations some kind of search engines would be more appropriate.

Comment: Why all the complexity for just a couple of million records? To be honest, I get the impression that the complexity is what makes things slow. Start with some good enough SQL statements and you should be good to go. The 1ms requirement is going to be complicated, any bitfart from the CPU or any network traffic will cause "unacceptable" delays.